# CakePHP: createdBy and updatedBy field

Tags: cakephp

Trying to create a 'magic' field like the created and modified field in CakePHP, but instead of storing a timestamp, I want a username that submitted the request.

Is there a way to pull in AuthComponent into the model, or do I need to do some magic with the AppController and always put a username field in the $this->data array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is available that logs who created or modified a model record.  http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/danfreak/2009/03/01/whodidit-behavior-automagic-created_by-and-modified_by-fields

If you don't wish to use it directly, it could serve as a reference for your own work.